# How to use validation working with a multi-tenant configuration in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, multi-tenant

I've made a multitenant Laravel app which mostly works.

The last configuration issue I have is about validation.

If I do the following as indicated [in docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic):

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

I will get the following error:

> "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'master.posts' doesn't exist

which is true because 'master' refers to the main database and not to the tenant one.

How could I configure validation on the tenant database?

Below is my MultiTenant Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $tenant_db = Auth::user()->tenant_db;
    Config::set('database.connections.tenant_mysql.database', $tenant_db);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `unique` rule allows specifying the connection to use when checking for uniqueness.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique):

> **Custom Database Connection**
>
> Occasionally, you may need to set a custom connection for database
>   queries made by the Validator. As seen above, setting `unique:users` as
>   a validation rule will use the default database connection to query
>   the database. To override this, specify the connection and the table
>   name using "dot" syntax:
>
> ```
> 'email' => 'unique:connection.users,email_address'
> ```

So in your case, your validation rules would change to:

```
'title' => 'required|unique:tenant_mysql.posts|max:255',
```

Comment: Using the Rule class is a lot easier: Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Unique::unique('table', 'column')->where()... https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-rule-objects

Comment: Thanks. This information allowed me to finish a long time error. For anybody looking for more info about this topic: https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-unique